# How to bind userControls inside a DataRepeater in Windows Forms c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, dataset, datarepeater

How to bind userControls inside a DataRepeater in Windows Forms c#?

I don't want to use this method: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsdata/archive/2009/08/12/datarepeater-control-for-windows-forms.aspx but I want to make the binding from a DataSet/DataTable programmatically. 
Inside the repeater just for tests I put one textbox and one label. Also one UserControl which consists also of two controls: one label and one textbox. 
So far only first label and textbox are updated but not the usercontrol. What do I miss?

This is the Load event

```
private void DataRepeaterForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ADRIAN-PC; Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2008R2; Integrated Security=true;User id=;password=");

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Person.Person", con);
            SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            DataTable items = new DataTable();
            adapt.Fill(items);

            textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", items, "FirstName");
            label1.DataBindings.Add("Text", items, "LastName");

            TextBox myUcTextBox1 = (TextBox)myUC1.Controls.Find("textBox1", true).First();

            if( myUcTextBox1 != null)
                myUcTextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", items, "LastName");

            dataRepeater1.DataSource = items;
        }
```

Should I also use other events like DrawItem, ... ?
regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx) to add bindings:

```
BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();
bindingSource1.DataSource = items;
textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "FirstName");
label1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "LastName");
dataRepeater1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
```

Comment: this does not save my issue, controls of usercontrol inside dataRepeater are not bound.

Comment: @AlexaAdrian verify if you have any data in your DataTable

Comment: I do. In the meaning time I got to a solution: I created properties in userControl, so I accessed textbox and label as a property with get and set. Now is working

Comment: MyUC myUC1 = ((MyUC)e.DataRepeaterItem.Controls.Find("myUC1", true)[0]);
            myUC1.TxtBox1 = PersonsDT.Rows[e.DataRepeaterItem.ItemIndex]["FirstName"].ToString();
            myUC1.LblCtrl1 = PersonsDT.Rows[e.DataRepeaterItem.ItemIndex]["LastName"].ToString();

Comment: public partial class MyUC : UserControl
    {
        public string TxtBox1
        {
            get { return textBox1.Text; }
            set { textBox1.Text = value; }
        }
        public string LblCtrl1
        {
            get { return labelControl1.Text; }
            set { labelControl1.Text = value; }
        }

Comment: however now I want to bind a comboBox inside the UC. and I have no clue about that :|

Comment: @AlexaAdrian sorry, didn't try to use user control. With simple textBox and label all works fine. I'll verify that in 30 minutes

Comment: @AlexaAdrian verified - with user control just create public properties and bind them to bindingsource. Same with combobox - use it's SelectedItem property for binding. Also you need to fill combobox with possible values (this is not binding part)